# session does not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My Session is not working Properly.
My session set code like:

```
$data=array('username'=>$this->input->post('txtname'),
                            'password'=>$this->input->post('txtpass')
                        );  
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

When i unset the session like:

```
$arr=array('username'=>'','password'=>'');
$this->session->unset_userdata($arr);
```

i am getting the array value null but when i clicked on logout then it shows login page but when i clicked on back button it displays last page information(Username).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your session almost destroy

you need to [redirect](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) when you destroy your session and you need flash data.

For example.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("success", $strMessage);
redirect("account/register");
```

And add this code on your index.php file

```
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Note that have to read flash data in your login panel `$this->session->flashdata('success');`

Comment: i had already redirected to the login page and it also works but when i clicked on back button of browser i am getting the last username page

Comment: Thank you it works.. when i clicked on back button after logout then it does not display the username page and ask me for form resubmission but when i reload that page it again shows that username page

Comment: @kavinipatel you have problem of form re-submission . its a common problem in browser. You will store a message in a cookie or session. Then Redirect after the post. Then you read the cookie/session and then clear the value of that session or cookie variable.

Comment: did you read flash data ? you also need to read flash data like `$this->session->flashdata('item');` flash data automatically destroy when its read.